# Expanding struct fields in C

Tags: c

Assume I have this struct which is defined in the `sim.h` header file given to user:

```
    typedef struct {
    cmd cmd;      /// The processed command in each pipe stage
    intt src1;
    int src2;  /// Actual value of src2 (considering forwarding mux, etc.)
} PipeStage;
```

Assume now I want to expand it's fields in the `sim.c` file.. How can I do it?

```
 typedef struct pipeStage{
    cmd cmd;
    pc_t PCofCmd;
    int src1;
    int src2;
    int dstVal;
} PipeState;
```

is it even possible?

Comment: No way. Not possible.

Comment: By making the first `struct` a member of the next `struct`.

Comment: Note that having a tagless structure type called `PipeStage` and then a tagged `struct PipeStage` called `PipeState` is a recipe for confusion on the part of the humans trying to read your code.  I suggest using the same tag and typedef names (`typedef struct SomeTag SomeTag;`).  If you don't like that, at least keep separate names separate — and use some commonality between the tag and the type names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **[Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane)** stated in the comments, you can define a new `struct` with one (or more) fields being of the other `struct`(s) type:

```
typedef struct {
    cmd cmd;      /// The processed command in each pipe stage
    int src1;
    int src2;  /// Actual value of src2 (considering forwarding mux, etc.)
} PipeStage;

typedef struct pipeStage{
    // cmd cmd;
    // int src1;
    // int src2;
    PipeStage stage; // or it might be a pointer: PipeStage *p_stage;
    pc_t PCofCmd;
    int dstVal;
} PipeState;
```

**Note**

If the order of the fields is important and `pc_t PCofCmd` should be right after `cmd cmd;` then you don't have too much chose but to define a new `struct` as is:

```
typedef struct pipeStage{
    cmd cmd;
    pc_t PCofCmd;
    int src1;
    int src2;
    int dstVal;
} PipeState;
```